# Remove first occurance of trailing slash in php

Tags: php, string, relative-path

I have code like this..

```
$dir['subdir'];
```

It returns value like this

```
/2012/12/14
```

Now I would like to remove the first trailing slash..

I mean I need like this

```
2012/12/14
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ltrim` function as:

```
$result = ltrim( ltrim($dir['subdir']), '/');
```

The inner ltrim removes leading whitespace and the outer ltrim removes the `/` as you want it.